# SELECT SUM(DISTINCT values) across multiple columns in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, unpivot

I have a MySQL table with 5 columns to store various values. For each record in the table the 5 columns store a single value (one of about 15). Here's an example of the structure:

```
| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 |  COL4 |  COL5 |
|------|------|------|-------|-------|
| val1 | val3 | val8 | val11 | val14 |
| val2 | val3 | val5 |  val9 | val12 |
| val1 | val2 | val6 | val14 | val15 |
| val3 | val5 | val9 | val10 | val12 |
| val2 | val4 | val7 | val11 | val14 |
```

I'd like to create a query that sums the unique values across each of those 5 columns. The result should show total number of times val1, val2, val3, etc are present across the 5 columns.

Ideally the result would be structured as:

```
val  | total
_____________________

val1 |  34

val2 |  12

val3 |  23

val4 |  14

val5 |  21

etc  |  etc
```

Thanks in advance for the help, much appreciated.

Comment: add some sample data, what do you have so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way: [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c31cc/1)

```
SELECT val,
       COUNT(*) AS total
FROM   (SELECT Col1 AS Val
        FROM   YourTable
        UNION ALL
        SELECT Col2 AS Val
        FROM   YourTable
        UNION ALL
        SELECT Col3 AS Val
        FROM   YourTable
        UNION ALL
        SELECT Col4 AS Val
        FROM   YourTable
        UNION ALL
        SELECT Col5 AS Val
        FROM   YourTable) AS T
GROUP  BY val
```

Or another: [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c31cc/3)

```
SELECT CASE N
         WHEN 1 THEN Col1
         WHEN 2 THEN Col2
         WHEN 3 THEN Col3
         WHEN 4 THEN Col4
         WHEN 5 THEN Col5
       END AS Val,
       COUNT(*) AS total
FROM   YourTable
       CROSS JOIN (SELECT 1 AS N
                   UNION ALL
                   SELECT 2
                   UNION ALL
                   SELECT 3
                   UNION ALL
                   SELECT 4
                   UNION ALL
                   SELECT 5) AS T
GROUP  BY Val
```

Comment: Great work! The first solution worked perfectly. Thanks for the help.